# Can anyone help me to find a syntax error?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm running this code in selenium, and it doesn't want to tell me where exactly the problem is, but I know that this function is the culprit:

```
function extractText(obj) {
  let result = "";
  for (const page of obj.pages) {
    for (const block of page.blocks) {
      for (const paragraph of block.paragraphs) {
        for (const word of paragraph.words) {
          for (const symbol of word.symbols) {
            result += symbol.text;
          }
        }
        result += "\n";
      }
      result += "\n";
    }
    result += "\n";
  }
  return result;
}
```

`JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token`

Do you see any errors in my code?

I tried to use some validators, but they don't tell me a thing. Chatgpt doesn't help too...

This doesn't pass either...

```
function extractText(obj) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.pages.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < obj.pages[i].blocks.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < obj.pages[i].blocks[j].paragraphs.length; k++) {
        for (let l = 0; l < obj.pages[i].blocks[j].paragraphs[k].words.length; l++) {
          for (let m = 0; m < obj.pages[i].blocks[j].paragraphs[k].words[l].symbols.length; m++) {
            result += obj.pages[i].blocks[j].paragraphs[k].words[l].symbols[m].text;
          }
        }
        result += "\n";
      }
      result += "\n";
    }
    result += "\n";
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: This is *very likely* not a JS problem. If you're doing it in Selenium, I assume you pass in a string with the code to run in the JS executor of Selenium. And further, I assume that the string of code doesn't actually then convert properly to code. E.g., if you *didn't* double escape the `\n` then the string of code would output `"` then *a new line* (not an escape sequence that denotes a newline in a string literal) then another `"`. And multiline string literals *are* a syntax error. Just a guess, though but there might be other problems due to using a string of code.

Comment: The script is a raw string in google colab, I'm passing an argument with python's "%" operator.
`script = """ some script ... [this function]... return [call that function](%s) """`
`wd.execute_script(script % base64)`

Answer (score 0):

As VLAZ said, I had to double escape the "\n", because it has something to do with formatting in python.